# Inconsistent build classes package structure with gradle java pugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to run a simple gradle build with just one line in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Java file is placed under- **src/main/java/hello/Hello.java**

When I run build.gradle, compiled Hello.class is generated under

**build/classes/java/main/hello/Hello.class**

What am I expecting is:

**build/classes/main/java/hello/Hello.class**

Hello.java-

```
package hello;
class Hello{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
     System.out.println("Hello Java");  
    }  
}
```

Can someone please explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This changed between Gradle 3.x and 4.x.

> The reason we went with build/classes/java/main vs build/classes/main/java is that it was less likely to break in strange ways with builds and plugins that hardcoded the path to build/classes/main or snuck outputs into build/classes/main.

from [Gradle forum discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/build-path-for-java-classes-changed-from-3-x-to-4-x/24168/7)